# htaccess 301 redirects, not sure about correct regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Can anyone help me, I am trying to sort out some redirects using htaccess but I am facing a tricky issue.

The part I cannot figure out is this: I have a system which creates 2 urls for some pages of the following pattern:

products/category (what we are using mostly and what we want, regardless of category depth)
products/subcategory/category (better for SEO maybe but not what we want)

How can I write a 301 redirect to strip out the /subcategory part of the url and redirect to the shorter version where we have in the region of 80 subcategories so I don't want to attempt this one by one. I am trying to get to grips with Regex but I am totally green with it, I am assuming matching the subcategory isn't too hard as it always follows /product and always ends with / but how do I redirect it to the shortened version.

I can't think of more information to add but if I haven't given enough detail let me know, I would love some help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these lines in your htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/[^/]+/(.+)$ /products/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: I will give you this tutorial to regular expressions, you can reed it to understand better how regex works (it is a little long but contains everything) http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Oh, I should have picked up on it, this matches anything I really need it to match only "products/subcategory" not "anything/anything", I'm trying to adapt your code but struggling, any help?

Comment: I have the book mastering regular expressions, and it's great so I get some of what I see here. It's just a whole new way of looking into code. I am trying to get that first expression to only match if it ends "products" but can't figure it out.

Comment: Any help, honestly I can't see how to match it only when it contains products/ in the url.

Comment: I edited my code so that it only matches urls starting with products if thats what you need

Comment: I will check it when I am back in the office tomorrow but thanks so much for your help.